# Why does numba's parallel=True make this computation 3 times slower?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

When doing this:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def doit(A, Q, n):
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])

A = np.random.random(1000*1000)
n = 5000
Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)    
doit(A, Q, n)
```

the runtime takes ~ 5.4 seconds on my computer.

I tried to use numba's parallelization feature:

```
@jit(parallel=True)
def doit(A, Q, n):
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
```

and instead, it takes 17 seconds.

**Why does numba's `parallel=True` make this computation 3 times slower instead of faster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer: one character was missing: **p**range instead of range:

```
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(parallel=True)
def doit(A, Q, n):
    for i in prange(len(Q)):
       ...
```

Then it takes 1.8 seconds instead of 5.4 seconds: the parallelization worked.